# classic asp stored procedures parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, vbscript, asp-classic

I've been looking around how to call a stored procedure from classic asp and pass a parameter into it below is my stored procedure which works fine

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Paging_Movies
@alphaChar char(1)
AS
if @alphaChar = '#'
select * from Movies where movies like '[^a-z]%'
else
select * from Movies where movies like @alphaChar + '%'
```

and my vbscript code so far -

```
Set objCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
set objComm = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

objCon.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxx;Initial Catalog=Movies;Data Source=xxxx-PC"

objComm.ActiveConnection = objCon
objComm.CommandType = 4
objComm.CommandText = "Paging_Movies"

objRS.open objComm.CommandText, objCon
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the Parameters property.

```
objComm.Parameters.Append objComm.CreateParameter("alphaChar", adChar, adParamInput)
objComm.Parameters("alphaChar") = "a"
objComm.Execute
```

Oh Lawdy I'm writing VBScript again.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the paramter  like as below

LInk for it : http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ado/quickref/command_createparameter.html

```
Set objParameter = objCommand.CreateParameter
objParameter.Name = "alphaChar"
objParameter.Type = adChar
objParameter.Direction = adParamInput
objParameter.Value = "a"
or
Set objParameter = objCommand.CreateParameter ("alphaChar", adChar, adParamInput, "a")
```